# Center an image that is cropped by responsive view

Tags: html, css, image

I have an  tag which stays at full height on mobile but the width is dropped (which is what I want). Now how do I centre this image? I have tried:

margin 0 auto
text-align: center

[image]

None if the usual image centring methods seem to work. You can view the image below:

http://helenshill.com.au/beta2/shop/

I have added:

width: 100%;

Which centres the image but also skews the dimensions. I want the image to maintain aspect ratio but be cut off and be centred.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Make the Question Clear.. What you actually need?

Comment: do you need .product img to resize ?

Comment: Why don't you use `background-image` for the whole background-container instead? Then you can use something like `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

CSS

```
.product img{
max-width:100%;
}
```

Hope this Helps...